# Concatenate a list of lists excluding one index

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a Pythonic way for concatenating a list of lists, excluding an index of choice? For example, if I had

```
[['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
```

and did not want index 1 in the result, my concatenated list would look like:

```
['a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

I could do this with a loop and checking against the iteration against my index of choice, but I'm hoping there's a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slicing:

```
from itertools import chain

ls = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]

list(chain.from_iterable(ls[:1] + ls[2:]))
```

If you want to avoid the cost of adding the slices together and creating new lists, it gets a bit more complicated:

```
from itertools import chain, islice
list(chain.from_iterable(chain(islice(ls, 1), islice(ls, 2, None))))
```

Comment: If you're going to use itertools you can also use `islice` to avoid temporary list creations.

Comment: I use up to date versions of Python, it doesn't create a list there.

Comment: but `ls[:1]` and `ls[2:]` both create new lists. Never mind, for such a problem that's total overkill anyway :)

Comment: @MSeifert Ah, my mistake, you're right. It does create new lists, even in Python 3. Overkill probably, but I'll still mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
lists = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
subset = [x for ind, x in enumerate(lists) if ind != 1]
subset # [['a'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
flattened = [item for l in subset for item in l]
flattened # ['a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

You could combine these into a single comprehension, I did it in two steps here to show more clearly what each part does.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using an external library I could offer [`remove`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/remove.html) and [`flatten`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/flatten.html) from [`iteration_utilities`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities)<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import remove, flatten

>>> l = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]

>>> list(flatten(remove(l, 1)))
['a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

---

<sup>1 I'm the author of that library.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

this is ~ *"I could do this with a loop and checking against the iteration against my index of choice...."*

but in a list comprehension, no libs

```
nix = 1

myls = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]

[e for ls in myls for e in ls if ls != myls[nix]]    

Out[11]: ['a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

no need for enumerate either

another of the slice and flatten possibilities that reads nice

```
sum(myls[:nix] + myls[nix+1:],[])
```

but some have a problem with the use of sum that way https://mathieularose.com/how-not-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-python/